# Simple Date Component in Swing

Tags: java, swing, date, jformattedtextfield

I was looking for open source for Date text field component. I tried some but I was looking for a component where user has to enter just numbers. User doesn't have  to enter the separator of day, month and year. For example, for the date '08-23-2015' (date format is MM-dd-yyyy) user just need to enter 08232015. He doesn't have to care about the separator (-).

Also when user moves caret back and forth in text field, it should skip the separator.
For example,

```
Initial caret position: |08-23-2015
User moves caret right: 0|8-23-2015
User moves caret right: 08-|23-2015
User moves caret left : 0|8-23-2015
```

Also it should support minimum date and maximum date constraint.

I have created a simple date component which I am sharing here, if someone is looking for similar kind of componet.

It can be fit for following formats

- MM-dd-yyyy

  MM-dd-yy

  dd-MM-yyyy

  dd-MM-yy

  yy-MM-dd

Source Link: https://github.com/ChitrangP/SimpleDateComponent

Answer (score 2):

Buddy it is a big work.

- **First step**

Create a `Number_Filter` class (*for check whether the entered value is number or not*.)
(If you need that class,please ask to me )

---

- **Second step**

Create your project and add necessary components,including the `Text box` for date entering.

Don't forget to add class to project file and create an object,like

```
Number_Filter obj_name = new Number_Filter();
```

---

- **Third step**

**on change event of text box--** add this much of code

a)Check number format by using

```
obj_name(Text_Date); //if not number it should clear the last typed digit/letter
```

b)Check the length of user input and put a slash or hyphen (/or-)after first 2
 digits-means(DD)of your date

```
if(Text_Date.gettext.toString.length()==1){  // second position
   Text_Date.settext(Text_Date.gettext.toString+"-")
  }
```

for eg-: if user type 28 ,at the same time (/or-) should be added.(*write code with respect to that basis*)

c)Same process should continue on next to digits-means (MM)

```
if(Text_Date.gettext.toString.length()==4){  // fifth position
   Text_Date.settext(Text_Date.gettext.toString+"-")
  }
```

for eg-: if user type 02 ,at the same time (/or-) should be added.(*write code with respect to that basis*)(DD-MM-)-->(28-02-)

c)Check the value in that date field which does not exceed 10 digits.like

```
if(Text_date.gettext.toString.length()>=9){
   //write code for delete the last inputed digit 
 }
```

Read it carefully and Do it till this

Comment: I hope you have read the README file and executed the test application I have shared.

I have several questions by looking at your reply and snippet you shared.

(1) Seems it is expecting the date field empty initially. I am wondering how it work on pre populated date.   
(2) Does it mean, if I wanted to use '/' as a separator, I need to make change in code?
(3) Does it mean, if I wanted to use 8 character date, I need to make change in code?
(4) What if I copy\paste part\entire of a date?
(5) When user moves caret in the text field, does it skip separator character?